# Assigning new column value to data frame based on if time series data matches functional constraint

Tags: python, pandas

I have the time series of a set of data for different samples. I would like to add a new column stating if the sample falls within a minimum and maximum constraint. If it does, I will assign the value 1 to the column, otherwise 0.

The example data frame I am using is below. The minimum constraint has the form y=-5t+30 and the maximum constraint has the form y=-5t+110. I would like to test the samples between time=2 and time=4.

I have thought to use np.where() to check each column beginning at 'time=2' and to 'time=4', but I am unsure how to loop through the data frame and unsure how to specify the time while looping through.

```py
ex_data=[['s1',50,50,50,50,50,50],['s2',120,110,100,90,80,70],['s3',30,70,110,70,30,10],['s4',10,30,70,110,70,30],['s5',55,30,20,15,5,0]]
df=pd.DataFrame(ex_data,columns=['sample','time=0','time=1','time=2','time=3','time=4','time=5'])
```

I expect the new column labeled success to be 1,0,0,0,0 for each respective row.

---

Edit 1:
Perhaps I was not specific enough. I would like the new column to be 1 if all the time steps match the constraint, otherwise 0.

---

Edit 2:

I was able to come up with the following solution.

```py
    def checking(s):
        mincon=[20,15,10]
        maxcon=[100,95,90]
        val=s.iloc[3:6]
        val=val.values
        for i in range(len(val)):
            if (val[i]<=mincon[i]) | (val[i]>=maxcon[i]):
                return 0
        return 1

    ex_data=[['s1',50,50,50,50,50,50],['s2',120,110,100,90,80,70], 
    ['s3',30,70,110,70,30,10],['s4',10,30,70,110,70,30],['s5',55,30,20,15,5,0]]
    df=pd.DataFrame(ex_data,columns= 
    ['sample','time=0','time=1','time=2','time=3','time=4','time=5'])
    df

    df['matches constraint?']=df.apply(checking,axis=1)
    df
```

I am not sure how to run this code on here, but it outputs what I want. Does anyone have suggestions for how I can speed this up when applying it to a muhc larger data set?

Comment: Make your data tidy, so that there is a column called `time` with a value running from `[0, n]`. Then, compare your value column and your minimum/maximum columns to determine whether it fits inside the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

First, tidy your data.

```
tidy = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames='time', i='sample', j='x', sep='=') \
    .reset_index().rename(columns={'time': 'value', 'x': 'time'})
# I made the choice to do some renaming to make it clearer what vars are what
```

Yield this sort of DataFrame (truncated):

```
  sample  time  value
0     s1     0     50
1     s2     0    120
2     s3     0     30
3     s4     0     10
4     s5     0     55
5     s1     1     50
```

Then, make sure it fits:

```
tidy['fits'] = (tidy['min'] < tidy.value) & (tidy.value < tidy['max'])
```

Yields this sort of DataFrame (truncated):

```
   sample  time  value  min  max   fits
0      s1     0     50   30  110   True
1      s2     0    120   30  110  False
2      s3     0     30   30  110  False
3      s4     0     10   30  110  False
4      s5     0     55   30  110   True
5      s1     1     50   25  105   True
6      s2     1    110   25  105  False
7      s3     1     70   25  105   True
```

If you want only the ones where time is in [2, 4], then subset the tidy DataFrame to that set (e.g. `tidy.query('2 <= time <= 4', inplace=True)`). If you want to use this to drop samples, then aggregate it from there and merge back to your original set, then do you subset command.